# How do I select only 1 row in sybase without using rowcount

Tags: sql, sybase, rowcount

How do I select only 1 row in sybase without using `rowcount`? I don't have the privilege to `set rowcount` in sybase. Is there a way to select only 1 row?

For example:

```
select * from table where name = 'jack'
```

This returns two rows; how do I select only one row from the result set without using `set rowcount`?

Answer (score 11):

Try the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mytable
WHERE name = 'jack'
```

As you might guess, this selects the TOP 1 matching results. If you wanted more (which you don't here) you could use any number (`TOP 100` or `TOP 1000`, etc).

A more comprehensive example can be found on w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a reason, why you're getting more than 1 row for "WHERE name = 'jack'", it looks as if the rows differ.

But if, the rows do not differ you can try adding "distinct":

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE WHERE name = 'jack'
```

or try with "GROUP BY" statement, then you should type explicitly all columns, eg.:

```
SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE name = 'jack' GROUP BY name
```

if this is not what you wanted, can you paste here how the 2 rows look exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single result, use 'GROUP BY' and 'HAVING column = max(column)'. Or replace max() with min(). 
This should work unless the max or min values are also not unique.